# Pass data to two tab bar view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to pass some data from my first view controller to two other view controllers, however as they are in a tab bar, I have been struggling with trying to do this through `prepareForSegue`. This is my code at the moment:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showRides") {
        var tabController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        var navController = tabController.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        var destController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! InitalViewController

        destController.parkPassed = parkSelected

        var tabController1 = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        var navController1 = tabController.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
        var destController1 = navController.viewControllers[1] as! MapViewController

        destController1.parkPassed = parkSelected
    }
}
```

I have also tried to pass the data from the first view controller to the first tab, and then to the second tab, but I didn't have any success with this either.

Anyone have any suggestions? That current code returns the error: `fatal error: Array index out of range` on the second to last line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to change my code to this:

```
        var tabController1 = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        var navController1 = tabController1.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
        var destController1 = navController1.viewControllers[0] as! MapViewController

        destController1.parkPassed = parkSelected
```

I had stupidly forgot to change some of the variable names, and I also had to change the index of the nav controller's view controller.